# Parallel hypersurfaces in a riemannian manifold and focal points

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For $M^n$ a riemannian manifold and $S$ a hypersurface, if we consider $$S_t=\{\exp^\perp(v):v\in T(S)^\perp,\;|v|=t\}$$ and $$f_t:S\rightarrow S_t:p\mapsto \exp^\perp(t\eta)$$ with $\eta$ the unit normal vector, then what is the relation of $f_t$ and the focal points of a geodesic $\gamma\perp S$?

We say that $f_t$ is a diffeomorphism for small $t$. How can we determine the value of $t$ where it stops being a diffeomorphism?

Any references on this material?

Answer (score 0):

My uneducated view (disposable if a real answer is posted) is that I think we can continue this process right until a focal point is reached, of the apparently [discrete set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149501/is-the-set-of-focal-points-of-a-submanifold-on-a-normal-geodesic-discrete)  of such points (references therein might be helpful too). Consider the unit sphere, we start from the equator to parallel disks at each latitude up until the north pole when $ t = 1 $.

Comment: Focal points are only one part of the story, they detect failure of the normal exponential map to be an immersion. However, an immersion need not be a diffeomorphism to its image because it fails to be injective. As an example, consider $n=2$, $S$ a simple closed geodesic and $M$ compact of negative curvature. There are no focal points in this situation, but, $f_t$ will fail to be injective for large $t$.